# android videoview mp4 seekto can only seek to every 10 seconds

Tags: android, mp4, android-videoview

i have an mp4 i am trying to view on my android in a video view but for some reason when i use seekto i can only seek to every 10 seconds. if i seek to 34 seconds it seeks to 30 and if i seek to 36 it seeks to 40. and so on for every thing i try to seek to. i have heard something about seek points in an mp4 file. is this whats causing my seek to fail?

```
    videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.watchMp4View);
            videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(uri));
            videoView.requestFocus();
            videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {




                        videoView.seekTo(timeToSkip); //
                        mediaPlayer.seekTo(timeToSkip);
                        mediaPlayer.setOnSeekCompleteListener(new MediaPlayer.OnSeekCompleteListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSeekComplete(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                                videoView.start();

 }
                        });
```

Comment: What's the GOP size on the video? Have you tried video files from other sources?

Comment: what is gop size? and i have tried many different resolutions and videos

Answer (score 1):

this issue is related to the creation of the `.mp4` file, your file need to be prepared to allow seeking, in the encoding process check the `Keyframe` property, try with a shorter `keyframe`.